# How to retrieve a data requested by user from django models?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a *model* and it has  **user** table as  "foreign key" in it . I need a query by which i can get user requested value .

Here is  my models:

```html
from django.db import models
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime    
 
from django.conf import settings

class schedulesdb(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateAndTime = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'],null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):              #  on Python 2
        return self.f_name
```

I was trying in this way I don't know what was wrong here :

Here is my views.py:

```html
def dashboard(request):
container=[]
DIR = os.path.realpath("/home/user/Desktop/Demo")
WAY = os.listdir(DIR)
for file in WAY:
    if file.endswith('.mp4'):
        file_name = file
        FDIR=os.path.join(DIR, file)
        container.append(FDIR)
        
return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'container': container})

def new_scheduler(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    f_name = request.POST.get('file')
    dateAndTime = request.POST.get('dateAndTime')
Scheduled_data = schedulesdb.objects.create(
        f_name = file,
        dateAndTime = dateAndTime,  
    )
Scheduled_data.save()
return HttpResponse ('done')


def new_job(request):
user = request.user
print user.username
print user.id
   
schedule_entries = schedulesdb.objects.filter(user=request.user)
print schedule_entries.dateAndTime


return HttpResponse(schedule_entries)
```

Here is my Traceback:

```html
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 17, 2016 - 16:10:43
Django version 1.8, using settings 'pro1.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
goku
2
[]
[17/Oct/2016 16:10:51]"GET /job/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Thanks in advance #peace

Comment: Have you already enabled `AuthenticationMiddleware`?

Comment: yes I did , I am able to print user and user.id

Comment: According to your output, you have no entries in the schedulesdb table for `user_id = 2`.

Comment: please have a look at snippet .. I'am saving data in scheduledb and user is foreign key , and I'am logged in as 'user_id = 2'

Comment: You can’t print a `QuerySet` like that.  Try: `print 'We have %s entries' % shedule_entries.count()`

Comment: I was logged in as `user_id =2 ` and I kept this default =1 here user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)

Comment: So that was the reason i was unable to get data once I made default value 2 then I was able to get data . But this way I'am getting all entries which I can even get through for loop , what I need is  user requested data .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to select all the records from `schedulesdb` model that relate to the current user, do the following.

```
def new_job(request):    
    schedule_entries = schedulesdb.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return HttpResponse(schedule_entries)
```

P.S. It is always better to follow the Python convention, so that other programmers can read your code faster. Start by reading the [PEP-8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)